# How to do SSO between two web services in intranet?

Tags: web-services, single-sign-on

The two web service(rest) are running on separated JVM instances with its own authentication.

The services is used by external user's log in, the server2 is for customer service team. After external use log in, he can call server2 for query. Oppositely, after customer service guy log in server2, he also can call server1 to change external user profile.

In another word, these two services trust each other. It seems like a SSO between them. Since both of them run on internal environment, I am wondering if there is a simple solution to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a good experience with [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/):

- The setup is relatively simple ([gateway](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Setup+JOSSO+Gateway+%28IdP%29) and [partner applications](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Setup+JOSSO+Agent+%28SP%29))
- Non [intrusive](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Jossify+your+JEE+Application) (no big changes needed for your application to work with it)
- Based on JAAS
- Supports various stores (LDAP, XML, DB...)
- Works with Java, PHP and ASP (we use Java and PHP at our company and it works flawlessly)

Comment: thank you for your reply. However open source sso solution is not in our road-map. To be honest, I also do not want to purchase a commercial solution for this project. I am working for a simple and suitable solution.

Comment: I would like to deal JOSSO/CAS as a backup plan. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of different options:

- You could roll your own authentication system. It'd be exactly what you need, but you get to debug it yourself.
- You could deploy [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29). A little old-school, but it clearly differentiates login servers from trusting servers.
- If you're already in an MS-heavy environment, [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_directory) might be just the tool.
- [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid) is the new kid on the block; as used by StackOverflow :) but implementations of servers and clients might be harder to find.
- [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldap) is an easy way to get site-wide directory services; actually doing authentication against it might be a bit more work. (Which is why Active Directory is as popular as it is -- combining LDAP with Kerberos into one mechanism for site-wide authentication and authorization. Neat.)

Comment: My scenario is one service uses LDAP and another is DB. It sounds like a typical case of SSO, however I am not sure if performance is fine to use web sso technology stack. Kerberos sounds good in case I generate it a free one.